# Android Adapter.RegisterDataSetObserver

Tags: android

What is RegisterDataSetObserver for? I looked for it almost everywhere (including the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver%28android.database.ContentObserver%29)), but I cannot find a proper answer.

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            list1.setSelection(adp.getCount()-1);
        }
    });
```

What is the purpose of this code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

Following the [Android Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29):

```
abstract void   registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
```

> Register an **observer** that is called when changes happen to the data
> used by this **adapter**.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ***observer***    -> the object that gets notified when the data set changes.

The [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) class:

> Receives call backs when a data set has been changed, or made invalid.
> The typically data sets that are observed are **Cursors** or **Adapters**.
>
> **DataSetObserver** must be implemented by objects which are added to a
> **DataSetObservable**.