# Android: adapter.registerDataSetObserver vs adapter.notifyDatasetChanged

Tags: java, android, android-listadapter

If I want to add views to GridView dynamically. So I was used threads and for every view, I was called `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`. 
Does `adapter.registerDatasetObserver()` gives optimization rather than `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() is better. Because adapter.registerDatasetObserver() you need to implement its observers and it not totally worth it. for more [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416865/android-adapter-registerdatasetobserver)